# Tomcat servlets and JFrame

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, jframe

I'm running a Tomcat server on my raspberry pi. When someone browses my server, the servlet launch a JFrame that shows some information on my TV (which is connected to the Pi).

This is how it's made, in the servlet:

```
public static JFrame gui;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException { // super.init() not needed
    if (gui==null) gui = launchUi();
    else if(!gui.isVisible()) gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem is, when I stop the server, the JFrame is not closed. This is what I found in the Tomcat logs.

```
janv. 20, 2014 9:53:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [AWT-Shutdown] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
janv. 20, 2014 9:53:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [AWT-EventQueue-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

How could I force the JFrame to be closed? Or I am doing it all wrong? (what's the right way then?)
Thanks

Comment: If it can display the `JFrame` in the first place, you should be able to destroy the frame in a `finalize` method.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the logic into `destroy()` method:

```
public void destroy() {
    gui.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: I also tried this
`@Override
public void destroy() {
    gui.setVisible(false);
    gui.dispose();
    gui = null;
}` but both error messages are still displayed

Comment: Actually you should not care about this error message. It is printed when tomcat un-deploys your application. But you said that it happens when tomcat is shutting down. This means that the process is closing anyway and all possible memory leaks are prevented by OS. The message is relevant only if you un-deploy application without shutting down the server. You can also try to find this thread by name and call `setDaemon(true)`. This will probably prevent this warning.

Comment: Thank you, I'll let as it is.